# Fragments disappearing after application has not been used for few hours

Tags: android, android-fragments, state

I am using [`SlidingMenu`](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) to open both right and left menu. It all works fine, except that I cannot find a way to preserve fragments' state after the app hasn't been used for at least few (~6) hours.

This is how I setup fragment in one of my menus:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null)
    mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(
        savedInstanceState, "mContent");
if (mContent == null)
    mContent = new SomeFragment();

setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, mContent).commit();
```

When the user comes back to the app after a longer period of time, some of the fragments (either fragment with the left or with the right menu) become gray and even though I am aware of it and I try the following solution (example for the left menu):

```
    mLeftMenuFragment = new LeftMenuFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.sliding_menu_left_content_frame,
            mLeftMenuFragment).commit();
```

it doesn't help.

Note that I have also tried the `commitAllowingStateLoss()` method (instead of `commit()`) but it didn't help either.

Comment: Probably the system killed you application. It should be fresh start without any problem (savedInstanceState should be null). Does killing the application manually (from ddms, or from application manager) has the same effect?

Comment: @kupsef I just killed it from the application manager and it saved the instance state correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think It would be better save state data in SharredPreferences or somewhere else and then recreate by hand. I think save Instance State better use for fast going back and forward or rotation and so on. Who knows what can happens in 6 hourse. Android can clean memor y or something else. You not controll it. It's my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the problem is not with a fragment, but with the content inside of it. Do you have an adapter for the content of your menu? Check it (maybe post the code of your fragment and corresponding view/adapter), it seems that after you reinflate a fragment it shows the same invalid view.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160836/fragments-disappears-after-resuming)

According to that try

ft.show(frag1);

should be

ft.attach(frag1); etc. if you're following this.

For more details http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs